# is there a way create counter with timeout() operator which is being used to timeout a observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

need to show a count down counter in UI for 10 second while waiting for below observable to emit.
if below observable does not emit with in 10 seconds its timed out. can the UI counter also be clubbed in the below code?

```
 this.authSubscription =     onauthReceived$.pipe(timeout({ first: 10 * 1000 })).subscribe({
            next: () => {
                console.log('do something)
            },
            error: err => {
                console.log('timed out before 7 seconds: ', err);
            },
            complete: () => {
                
                             console.log('complete)             
            }
        });
```

I have a different counter function but want to know if it can be clubbed so while waiting for observable to emit counter can be shown in UI.

Comment: What does it mean to be "clubbed"?

Comment: clubbed as in combine . combine the counter function and the above observable subscription. or anyway i can get the values of timeout values which can be shown in UI.

Comment: this might help: https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `combineLatest` operator to combine two or more streams:

```js
@Component(...)
export class App {
  authenticated$ = new Subject<string>();

  viewModel$ = combineLatest({
    authenticated: this.authenticated$.pipe(
      timeout(10 * 1000),
      startWith(null)
    ),
    countdown: timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map((count) => 10 - count),
      takeUntil(this.authenticated$)
    ),
  }).pipe(
    catchError(() =>
      of({
        authenticated: 'you were too late!',
        countdown: 0,
      })
    )
  );
}
```

In my example `viewModel$` is an observable stream that emits an object that has a `countdown` and an `authenticated` property, allowing you to show the value of `viewModel.countdown` in your template:

```html
<button (click)="authenticated$.next('authenticated!')">authenticate</button>
<pre>{{viewModel$ | async | json}}</pre>
```

Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jwyazf?file=src%2Fmain.ts